# bash: how do you print diff command output?

Tags: bash, diff

I want to use diff as an if statement condition but also output diff to stdout. However, when I put diff as a condition, it doesn't run the command/show the output:

```
if [ "diff -rq dir1 dir2" != "" ]
then
    echo "there are differences"
    exit 5
fi
```

I want this to output the differences when the two directories have differences, but this doesn't print the differences out and just outputs `there are differences`.

If I run `diff -rq dir1 dir2` **outside** of the if condition, it will print out `Only in dir1: xyz.txt`for example. I know I can write the command `diff -rq dir1 dir2` in the if statement `then` but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the literal string "diff -rq dir1 dir2" to the literal string "". Clearly these do not match, your `if` condition is satisfied, and your echo runs.

To accomplish what you want, leverage the fact that `diff` returns non-zero if and only if the files differ:

```
if ! diff -rq dir1 dir2; then
    echo "they differ"
    exit 5
fi
```

Don't bother comparing the output of `diff` to empty or not: that's not The UNIX Way.

Comment: Would it be right to write `if [ ! diff -rq dir1 dir2 ]`? I'm trying to put all the conditions in brackets, but it doesn't always work.

Comment: @book `[` is not shell syntax, it's just a funny name for a program that performs simple comparisons and tests. You can find it in `/usr/bin/[`. In this case you want to run the `diff` program instead.

Comment: @book Some would argue that it is never right to use `[` at all!  If you spell it `test` you will avoid the confusion caused by believing that `[` is part of the shell grammar.  If for some reason you don't like using `test` and want an operator that is part of the grammar, use `[[` but be aware that it's use is unspecified by the standard.  (That is, some shells do not recognize it, so if you use it you're restricting your script to those shells that do.)